# Import multiple Python classes from multiple files as if they belong to same file

Tags: python-3.x, module, python-import

I am built a python package used for my teams work and I have 4 classes that pretty much always get used together. Currently I have all the classes in one file and it's starting to pass 2000 lines. I would like to separate my classes into multiple files but have them work off of one import line to avoid breaking other peoples code.

For example lets say my package is myawesometools with a module foobar with two classes foo and bar. All code as been built with "from myawesometools import foobar as fb". Could I separate foo and bar into separate files and still have them belong to fb?

Another way to word this might be how can I have multiple files belong to same namespace like other languages like c# and c++ work?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do is create a folder under myawesometools named foobar, and in that folder you will add a file `__init__.py`. This will make this folder a package.
then in that folder you can add all the separate files. In the end you can just write

```
from foo import foo
from bar import bar
...
```

And now you can just do `from myawesometools import foobar as fb`